# MultivaluedMap exception

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, atmosphere

I am trying to run one sample of atmosphere  but when i run the Restful web services its giving me following error , i guess because of following code its generating error , i don't know what is wrong
i am using glassfish 3 and Netbeans IDE , here is the [sample](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples/rest-chat) link

```
 @Broadcast({XSSHtmlFilter.class, JsonpFilter.class})
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @POST
    public String publishMessage(MultivaluedMap<String, String> form) {
        String action = form.getFirst("action");
        String name = form.getFirst("name");

        if ("login".equals(action)) {
            return ("System Message" + "__" + name + " has joined.");
        } else if ("post".equals(action)) {
            return name + "__" + form.getFirst("message");
        } else {
            throw new WebApplicationException(422);
        }
    }



INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String
    SEVERE: The log message is null.
    java.lang.InstantiationException: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator$8.resolve(WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator.java:467)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlGenerator$ExternalGrammarDefinition.resolve(WadlGenerator.java:181)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.ApplicationDescription.resolve(ApplicationDescription.java:81)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator.attachTypes(WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator.java:518)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.WadlBuilder.generate(WadlBuilder.java:124)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.getApplication(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:104)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.getWadl(WadlResource.java:89)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:232)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
            at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:444)
            at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:308)
            at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
            at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
            at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
            at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:94)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
            at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
            at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:204)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
            at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
            at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
            at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
            at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
            at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

    INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
    INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String
    INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String
    INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String
```

**Run time error**

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.atmosphere.jersey.AtmosphereFilter$Filter.filter(AtmosphereFilter.java:177)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1008)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:232)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:444)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:308)
        at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:94)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
        at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Ouch, that's some old version of Jersey it's trying to use. Which version of the sample are you using? When I looked at the atmosphere site, the latest samples are using Jersey 1.9.1. The log says it's using 1.1.5.1. Which GF are you using? Are there other apps using other version of Jersey deployed on that GF instance?

Comment: i successfully deployed the build now , but when i try to run its giving me error , please have a look above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the com.sun.enterprise.overrideablejavaxpackages JVM property in GlassFish as advised in the [Overriding Jersey with war files](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/glassfish.html#d4e1927) section of Jersey user guide and restart GF.