# What is wrong with this request?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jersey

I am trying to make post request to jersey test method. But I am always getting an error and have no idea, what is wrong. I am using Tomcat.

Java code:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UsersResource {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey Today";
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String createUser(User us)
{
    //System.out.println("userdata " + us);
    User user = new User("testUserName", "testPassword");
    return user.toJson();
}
}
```

User class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class User 
{
private String username;
private String password;

public User()
{
    super();
}

public User(String name, String pass)
{
    super();
    this.username = name;
    this.password = pass;
}

public User(String username)
{
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String toJson()
{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(this);
    return json;
}
}
```

And js code:

```
$(function () {

main = {

    // Start updates
    start: function(){

        var user = {username: "test", password: "pass"};
        var encoded = $.toJSON( user );

        ajaxPost.ajaxRequest("TodoListing/rest/users", user,
                            function(data)
                            {
                                alert("success with data " + data);
                            }, 

                            function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("error " + textStatus + "/" + errorThrown);
                            });

    }
},

// Ajax request.
ajaxPost = {
    ajaxRequest: function(service, data, successSelector, errorSelector) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxPost.serverURL + service,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "application/json",
            success: successSelector,
            error: errorSelector
        });
    },
    serverURL: 'http://localhost/',
};

});
```

JS always returns error without description(empty errorThrown) and jersey logs an error on request:

```
PM com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator attachTypes
INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class java.lang.String
```

Comment: Try using [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) or curl instead of JS to make a request, so you can determine if it's really the server that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Glassfish server, then you need to set `com.sun.enterprise.overrideablejavaxpackages` to JVM. Moreover there is a thread here:

[MultivaluedMap exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840620/multivaluedmap-exception)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am using Tomcat.

Answer (score 7):

I run into the same problem with jersey and grizzly getting the same error all the time. After 2 weeks of research it appears that this problem relates to CORS (cross domain) difficulties.

The solution that works for me was a filter that gives some additional information to the response header:

```
    import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
    import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
    import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

    class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

        @Override
        public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
            // instead of "*" you should provide a specific domain name for security reasons
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            return response;
        }
    }
```

introducing the filter to grizzly:

```
    ...
    ResourceConfig rc = new ClasspathResourceConfig("my.resource.package");
    rc.getContainerResponseFilters().add(new CORSFilter());
    return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer("http://base_uri", rc);
    ...
```

Maybe you can adopt this to tomcat.